# How to tell if last method in chain?

Tags: php, oop, methods

I've started using method chains in my PHP app:

`$object->do()->something();`

Specifically with querying databases:

`$database->select()->from('mytable');`

However at the moment I need to call a function to actually perform the query at the end:

`$database->select()->from('mytable')->perform();`

This is annoying because usually every chain will perform straight away. Sometimes it wouldn't, but 9 times out of 10 it will. I need this to work with any object, not just a database handler.

**Is there a way to tell if the last method I call is the last one in the method itself**, so it would `perform()` without me telling it to?

If not, I might just try to use some keywords like `->now()` instead of `->perform()`

I have a few idea(s):

- each method has a parameter that if set will let it know it's at the end (maybe it can loop through all parameters to find if a special constant was passed?) eg `$object->do()->something(now);`

Comment: Please don't chain methods. You are violating [CQS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command–query_separation).

Comment: @tereško "it is clearly intended as a programming guideline rather than a rule for good coding"

Comment: *"it is clearly intended as a programming guideline rather than a rule for good coding, **such as avoiding the use of a `goto` from a nested loop.**"* Also, please see: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html

Answer (score 1):

In Perl's DBIX::Class they trigger the query upon using the data. So each query chain doesn't return the database object but a DBIX::Class object that wraps around the database table object.

You can possibly try to implement a similar system. So, for example the following:

```
$resultSet = $database->select()->from('mytable');
```

does not actually return the table but a resultSet object. And only when you try to do:

```
$resultSet->next();
```

will the library actually fetch the data from the database.

Basically, all the accessor methods like `first()`, `last()`, `all()` and `next()` fetch and cache the data. If the data has already been fetched and is cached in memory then further calls to accessor methods on the resultSet object should just read the hash in memory instead of connecting to the database.

---

Additional detail:

Inserts don't have complex clauses like select. So the inserting function doesn't need to be chainable. So for inserts, you can simply have the API do something like this:

```
$database->insert()->into('mytable')->values({
    foo => "hello",
    bar => "world"
});
```

where the `values()` method act as the inserting function and triggers the database query.

Updates can simply be done on the row object. You can have the API do something like this:

```
$row = $database->select()->from('mytable')->first();
$row->foo('goodbye');
$row->update();
```

or alternatively:

```
$row->update({
    foo => "goodbye"
});
```

And have the `update()` method trigger the database query.

Comment: Actually fetching the data when I use it sounds pretty good. How does it handle updating/inserting rows, creating tables, etc.?

Comment: Also implementing this with non-database classes sounds tricky. Do you know of a way (otherwise I'll have a go myself)?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, inserting rows and updating the db simply causes it to delete its internal hash. Trying to read the data will cause another database query to be made. I believe this is configurable with the default to reload from the db just to be safe.

Comment: The core concept is that you have the data in memory but if the data cache is empty (`undef` in perl) then read the data from file/network. This is also typically implemented by templating libraries such as Template Toolkit. The only difference is that the data object also stores the constructed query that created it so that the query can be modified before the actual data is fetched or repeated if the data needs to be refreshed.

Comment: You can easily implement a file reader with this technique which maps query params to file on disk and then only reads the file when you call its `next_line()` method. Or another idea a css or js roll-up utility with the same idea allowing you to keep adding css or js files to the object but only reading the files on disk when you call its `print()` method.

Comment: I mean inserts and updates shouldn't need a `first()`, `last()`, `next()`, etc. call, so the query won't be called. When you start chaining an insert or update, how do you trigger the query?

Comment: Inserts should not need chaining since it really doesn't make sense. There's no where clause for inserts. So for insert it simply uses the table object/class and calls the insert method directly on it with a hash. For updates it simply calls the `update()` method of the row object.

Answer (score 0):

Using an operator overloading [extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator), you can specify one of the unary operators for prompting executions

Example:

```
~$db->select()->from()->where();
```

If you want to avoid installing an extension, one suggestion I can make is using some kind of escape character in your latest chain call to promp the execution. You should omit it from the final query to avoid syntax errors.

Example:

```
$db->select()->from()->where("id = 1 ~"); //~ character implies automatic execution
```

Comment: I feel uneasy about overloading operators and using extensions. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell if the last method I call is the last one in the method itself

No, I believe there is no such thing. That's because "chain calls" do not differ from "one by one calls". That's just a kind of syntactic sugar for "call => return object => call => return object ..." chain.

```
I have a few idea(s):

 - each method has a parameter that if set will let it know it's at the end (maybe it can 
   loop through all parameters to find if a special constant was passed?) eg
   $object->do()->something(now);
```

You can achieve an effect of an idea you suggested by [overloading `__call()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call). This way you can abstract your parameter checking logic nicely.

But be aware, that such behaviour is not really obvious architecture-wise and you probably should consider PDO-like approach, that is using "finalizing" method like `perform()` or `do()` which, I think, you already have.

Comment: Overloading the `__call()` method is a neat idea. You are correct in that I already use a finalise method (currently `perform()`).